# Como puedo hacer esto en Haskell

Tags: haskell

estoy haciendo unos ejercicios y me he quedado atascado en el 3.4. Me piden definir una función que dada una lista devuelva la lista inversa. **NO PUEDO USAR LA FUNCION REVERSE**. Para completar esta tarea tengo que usar las funciones que me piden en el 3.1 y 3.3 cuyos código voy a adjuntar ahora.

```
import Data.List

--3.1
posinv::[t] -> [(Integer,t)]
posinv s
 |null s = []
 |otherwise = zip (reverse [1..(genericLength s)]) s
--Ejemplo de lo que hace: posinv [19,56,15] = [(3,19),(2,56),(1,15)]

--3.2
lista_indice::Integer -> [(Integer,t)]->[(Integer,t)]
lista_indice i s = [(x,t) | (x,t) <- s, x == i]
--Ejemplo de lo que hace: lista_indice 2 [(3,19),(2,56),(1,15)] = [(2,56)]

--3.3
lista_indices:: Integer -> [(Integer,t)] -> [[(Integer,t)]]
lista_indices n s  = [lista_indice x s | x <- [1..n] ]
--Ejemplo de lo que hace: lista_indices 3 [(3,19),(2,56),(1,15)] = [[(1,15)],[(2,56)],[(3,19)]]

--3.4
inversa::[t]-> [t]
inversa s = concat [y | y <- (x,y) <- (lista_indices (genericLength s) (posinv s)) ]

--Lo que debería de dar: inversa [19,56,15] = [15,56,19]
```

Bien, como me piden sí o sí que use las funciones 3.1 y 3.3 para completar el 3.4, `(lista_indices (genericLength s) (posinv s))`con esto de aquí consigo lo que hace la función 3.3, es decir,  [[(1,15)],[(2,56)],[(3,19)]]. Si os fijais, es casi resultado solo que debería de concatenar `[[15],[56][19]]` , solo que no sé como hacer para conseguir esto mismo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es sencillo con *asignación de patrones*:

```hs
inversa :: [t] -> [t]
inversa xs = [ x | [(_, x)] <- lista_indices (genericLength xs) (posinv xs) ]
```